# How to declare types for Vuex bindings on Vue component?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I'm using Vuex `mapState` on a Vue component (using `Vue.extend`, not class style):

```
  computed: {
    ...mapState('geoframes/create', [
      'apiRequestId',
      'countPending',
      'deviceCount',
      'requestId',
    ]),
```

Methods in the Vue component referencing `this.deviceCount`, for example, are throwing TS errors because it doesn't realize these are bound to the component via Vuex.

How do I address this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's actually a bug in Vuex.

https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1353